# CSS "wrapper" div background color not appearing in 2nd div?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova-2.7.0

**"wrapper" div background color not appearing in 2nd div while height and width of both div is defined**
why background color is not applied in whole width and height as defined in wrapper its not applied in  #leftSideContent div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>page practice</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            background-image: url("stripe_f4b448da7a886ae96535955b68f80e83.png");
            background-repeat: repeat;
        }
        #wrapper
        {
            width:700px;
            margin-left:300px;
            margin-right:300px;
            background-color:#deb887;
        }
 #firstAside
        {
            border:8px aquamarine solid;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            width:200px;
            height:375px ;

        }
        #secondAside
        {
            border:8px aquamarine solid;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            width:200px;
            height:100px ;

        }
nav
        {
            margin-top:10px;
            margin-left: 3px;
        }
        #leftSideContent
        {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 700px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <p>CSS Zen Garden</p>
        </header>
        <div id="leftSideContent">
        <aside id="firstAside">
          <b>Select A Design</b>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">JAMES KERLEY</a> <span> by </span><a href="#">ABCD</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">JAMES KERLEY</a> <span> by </span><a href="#">ABCD</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          </aside>
        <aside id="secondAside">
            <b>Archives</b>
            <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">JAMES KERLEY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JAMES KERLEY</a></li>
             </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>
</div>
          <div id="content"><p> data</p></div>
         </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[fiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/erum/GeSQ2/embedded/result/)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with your code please.

Comment: please see edited question i have added fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#wrapper` declaration block.

Comment: overflow :hidden;   removes my last div last line contents

Comment: i have metioned overflow:hidden  ;  height:1000px;  is it right please inform me

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the last declaration `height:1000px;`

Answer (score 1):

there is only one problem with code: 
i need to define height of #wrapper div that was the only mistake 
now wrapper div CSS will be :

```
 #wrapper
        {
            width:700px;
            margin-left:300px;
            margin-right:300px;
            background-color:#deb887;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `#wrapper` color to appear under `#leftsidecontent`, all you have to do is add `overflow: hidden` to `#wrapper`. This happens when you float a child element.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't cleared your float. Add `<br clear="all"/>` for older HTML somewhere before `#wrapper` closes. OR, use CSS and apply `overflow: auto;` to `#wrapper`.

CSS Method: http://jsfiddle.net/GeSQ2/1/
HTML Method: http://jsfiddle.net/GeSQ2/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's because `#leftSideContent` is floated outside the `#wrapper`.

Add `overflow: auto` to `#wrapper` so that it knows that there is something floating out.